# MySQL: "AND" condition within several rows

Tags: mysql, group-by

Table looks like this:

```
id | event_id | date |

  1 | 2 | 2016-04-29
  2 | 2 | 2016-04-31
  3 | 1 | 2016-04-30
  4 | 1 | 2016-04-31
```

I need to run a query, which would return **grouped event_ids**, which would have **ALL the dates** between requested period.

For example, looking in the table above:

If query is `(=> 2016-04-29 )` : `( <= 2016-04-31 )`, no event should be returned.

If query is `(=> 2016-04-30 )` : `( <= 2016-04-31 )`, event_id = 1 should be returned.

How to solve this?

Comment: please update your desired o/p

Comment: why _If query is 2016-04-29 : 2016-04-31_ should return no events?

Comment: Yes, because `event 2`doesnt have `2016-04-30` date and `event 1` doesnt have `2016-04-29` date. Look closely )

Comment: but all the dates are between 2016-04-29 and 2016-04-31

Comment: This is odd, I think some over-normalization has been done here. It should really be an events table with ID, date_start, date_end. This setup is going to be prone to duplication of events.

Answer (score 1):

you think about something like this:

```
SELECT event_id AS eid FROM `test` WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-04-30' AND '2016-04-31'
GROUP BY event_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test` WHERE event_id = eid)
```

or this:

```
SELECT event_id AS eid FROM `test` WHERE date IN ('2016-04-30', '2016-04-31')
GROUP BY event_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test` WHERE event_id = eid)
```

*BTW April has only 30 days*

Comment: I think for this task he need BETWEEN, IN doesn't account for the range of dates.

Comment: I know by I don't undestand why  _If query is (=> 2016-04-29 ) : ( <= 2016-04-31 ), no event should be returned._. In example all dates are between 29 and 31 of April. Cause I gave an example with `IN ()`

Answer (score 0):

You should get the solution by below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.event_id FROM Event_tbl e1 
    WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(e2.event_id)) FROM Event_tbl e2 WHERE (e2.date BETWEEN '2016-04-30' AND'2016-04-31')) = 1 
    AND
e1.date BETWEEN '2016-04-30' AND'2016-04-31'
```